# What is the meaning of "your first interest" in this novel by John Galsworthy?

Tags: meaning, john-galsworthy, a-stoic

I'm translating a novel by John Galsworthy, *A Stoic,* written at the beginning of the XX century ([full text on Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2684/2684-h/2684-h.htm)), and I've come across a sentence I’m finding quite tricky to understand:

> This'll be your first interest-on six thousand pounds?

The context is as follows: a man has made a settlement of six thousand pounds at four and a half per cent on a lady (the one who’s being asked here). A solicitor comes to her house and asks her the question above after saying: “I am a solicitor though; came just to ask about a certain settlement that Mr. Pillin tells me you're entitled under.” What is the meaning of “your first interest” here?

Comment: Hi, avx! For any future questions, please add a work tag (I've edited in [[tag:a-stoic]]) and an author tag (I've edited in [[tag:john-galsworthy]]) if applicable. These help with categorizing content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A settlement of

> six thousand pounds at four and a half per cent

means that £6,000 has been invested at a return of 4.5% interest on the capital. The interest is paid out to the investor, whoever the person the investor has ‘settled’ it on. In this case it is Mrs Larne who is so ‘entitled’.

The lady is about to receive the first of her quarterly  instalments of the interest, though by my calculation 1/4 of 4.5% on 6,000 would be £67 and 10 shillings rather than £60. Perhaps the rest gets eaten up in bankers’ charges.